# Adding artwork to video files extremely slow in iTunes

Tags: itunes, album-art

I am using Handbrake to create ATV2-compatible video files using their included preset. After importing these files into iTunes, when I try to add artwork to them it seems to rewrite the entire video file to disk. Is there any way to speed up this process? My first guess is that there's something wrong with the format/container coming out of Handbrake.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!